# how to render react component dynamically

Tags: reactjs

I am try to call component in a page dynamically. For example based on some logic will fetch component from json file, as below

```
[{"page":{"pageType": "sales","componentName":  "<SaleList res={grid} />"}}]
```

When I am doing like this

```
const dymComp = <SaleList res={grid} /> 

{dymComp}
```

its working fine.
But when I am fetching it from json, it's rendering as string on page rather call as a component

Thanks in advance for any clues / help

Comment: I believe what you're asking for is impossible. If you really want to go this route, I suggest you create a function with a `switch` statement that takes `pageType` and `componentName` as arguments and returns an actual `React` component, which is a `function`, not a `string`.

Comment: have you tried React.createElement() ?

Comment: @AlirezaYadegari wouldn't you have to pass an actual `React` component rather than just a `string`? How is `React` supposed to know what `"<SaleList res={grid} />"` means?

Answer (score 0):

when you want to create element dynamically you must use function to return an element(i mean you have to use {createDymComp()} instead of {dymComp}) ,
for function creator you have 2 options 1. use React.createElement() https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement according to your definition or you can use switch case to return specific component

```
    const firstElement = () => {return (<div></div>)}
const SecElement = () => {return (<div></div>)}

const yourCOmponent = (props) => { 

  function elementCreator(type){
switch(type) 
{
case '1':
  return firstElement; 
 case '2':
    return SecElement;
  }
}
    
    return (<div>{elementCreator(props.type)}</div>)
```

}

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you'd use `React.createElement` with the `JSON` data that OP provided?